# Is Microsoft Sync Framework alive?

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

According to the MS documentation Sync Framework Toolkit (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e) is a legacy open source product which MS no longer support:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839436(v=sql.110).aspx

That's fine, but how about Microsoft Sync SDK which is not open source? 
Does it mean that open source part useless because server part can be removed by MS in the future?

The question is does it mean that Sync Framework SDK (Server side library) is dead? (Green Part)
[image]

Comment: Did you ever find out more about this?

Comment: @NoOneSpecial. Unfortunately no, I was unable to find out more.

Comment: there's a similar question here...and kind of indicate is still alive...: https://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/par_servplat/forum/par_winserv/is-microsoft-sync-framework-deprecated/ed39b23b-1aaa-4538-83cb-28d6edb0619d

Comment: @NoOneSpecial Thanks for the reference, hope at least someone at MS will say YES or NO. According to this link support engineer make assumptions based on personal opinion and does not really know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what do you mean by dead.
As long as you know ***Sync Framework Toolkit*** is not supported and you know the consequences of using it.
As to ***Sync Framework SDK*** 
Some Federal agencies did approve the usage of that SDK.
This link might be the answer to your question.
According to the US department of Veteran Affairs 
https://www.oit.va.gov/Services/TRM/ToolPage.aspx?tid=11403
Microsoft Sync Framework Software Development Kit (SDK) Technology is approved with constraints in 2019, 2020, 2021

> Approved w/Constraints: The technology/standard can be used within the
>   specified constraints located below the decision matrix in the
>   footnote[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/synchronization/mt490616(v=msdn.10)) and on the General tab.

However, these constraints are not met.

> Technology must remain patched and operated in accordance with Federal
>   and Department security policies and guidelines in order to mitigate
>   known and future security vulnerabilities.

You might notice [this announcement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/synchronization/mt490616(v=msdn.10)) which does not seem to still be valid,
**Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 is now in extended support!**

> Starting from January 12, 2016, Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 (including SDK and redistributables) has entered extended support. This change has an impact on how you receive software updates and support for Microsoft Sync Framework. For more detailed information, refer to the Microsoft Support Lifecycle.

I hope that can be an acceptable answer to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has stopped supporting Sync Framework. We'd a ticket opened with MS for one of the framework issue, and got to know from MS that the team which has originally developed the framework is disbursed and there is no support available.

Comment: If you read my question more carefully you will see that I had different question.

Comment: @AccessDenied : Are you still searching for a solution ? If yes, take a look at https://github.com/Mimetis/Dotmim.Sync

Comment: @SébastienPertus Thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that open source part useless because server part can be
>   removed by MS in the future?

You can always download the [SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23217) and keep a copy, so I don't see a problem on the "Microsoft removing it" question.

> The question is does it mean that Sync Framework SDK (Server side
>   library) is dead?

In my opinion, yes. It is only a matter of time before the software won't work with an updated version of windows (last update to the SDK was August 2010). Once that happens or you discover a critical bug, you are stuck.