# Is there a successor for Sync Framework 2.1?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

we are using Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 in various customer projects for file and database sync. Extended Support will end in 2021.

So my questions are:

- What is Microsofts strategy for the sync framework? Is it going to be open  source, so we can change if needed ourselves? Is there a successor product that  we should / can migrate to?
- Is MSSF supported on Windows 10 and Server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my answer really helps, but lets see: Microsoft announced the official release of the "Azure SQL Data Sync" on June 18 2018. It is not truly a successor of the original framework, but it is basically all you get. Other "non cloud" frameworks have also started to fade away, since Microsoft treats server/desktop/on-premise only as an extension to the cloud. As the name indicates, it is targeting Azure and it is not for file sync, either.

I have seen your question also in the "old" Microsoft social network (social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home). In there they point to this framework in questions related to the original "Sync Framework" since something like 2012 (this was the oldest question I could associate with both frameworks).

Comment: Thank you Peter! Do you know anything about supported OSes for the old MSSF?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you question correctly: you mean if MSFT supports the framework at least on _some_ existing OSes?

Comment: Is MSSF supported on Windows 10 and Server 2016?

Comment: From my point of view you should _not_ consider it supported, see this stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149511/is-microsoft-sync-framework-alive?rq=1